# Getting reliable available width and height using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

**Background**

I'm having trouble getting a reliable viewport size using JavaScript. I've read through [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) to set up the application and [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html) to learn about targeting specific device resolutions.

This is the `<meta>` tag on the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

This allows me to use the sharpest images to draw the interface. To test the resolution I've written this piece of code:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {
    console.log(screen.availWidth + ' x ' + screen.availHeight)
}
// 1080 x 1920 or 1920 x 1080
```

**Problem 1**

I had hoped the actual available pixels could be calculated like:

```
width := screen.availWidth / devicePixelRatio
height := screen.availHeight / devicePixelRatio
```

But the `devicePixelRatio` is fixed at `3`, independent of the target dpi; so how can I determine the actual pixels at my disposal?

**Problem 2**

The above `screen.availHeight` is not accurate because it doesn't take into account the actual height of the `WebView` component.

I've tried these alternatives:

```
console.log(document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
// 1920
console.log(window.innerHeight);
// 240
```

These values are pretty much useless, and worse, they don't change when the screen rotates nor are they dependent on the target dpi. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe the values from jQuery width() and height() will return correct values for you? http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/

Comment: Hye jack please let me know how you got the size finally which works for you. I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's been quite awhile since I last worked with the android SDK and web views, *but* can't you simply expose the information from the java side where you can determine it reliably? So any time your orientation changes + initially you call

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:setResolution(x,y,orientation)");
```

and in your javascript you write the dimensions to a logical place.

It's not btw that this would be impossible from javascript, *but* any time I need to do anything remotely along the lines of what you want to do it takes a lot of trial and error to get it cross device supported, so personally I would advice you to use the fact that you have a webview to your advantage. (And if you are by any chance using a webview framework like cordova you can even relatively simply make a javascript plugin out of it)

Comment: Thanks. That thought did cross my mind :) having said that, it solves only one of the problems; the other problem is that of knowing how many `px` are at your disposal based on the device dpi. Do you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: Can't you simply use `DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();` and pass `metrics.xdpi;` `metrics.ydpi;` to your webview as outlined above? However if you're using `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` then that should be mostly useless except to determine 'in real life' sizes. Though to be honest I am not entirely sure what your end goal is.

Comment: Or it sounds like maybe you wanna use `metrics.widthPixels` and `metrics.heightPixels`, tough in the end it's the same thing.

Comment: With `DisplayMetrics` I can't tell whether the width available is `1080px` (target dpi) or `320px` (default dpi).

Comment: So you actually don't want to use `target-densitydpi=device-dpi`?

Comment: I do, what I'm trying to say is that the `device-dpi` is not always the same for each phone.

Comment: But you know what it is from `metrics.xdpi` and `metrics.ydpi`... I am probably just misunderstanding something, but you know what the DPI is and you know what the resolution is, with those two things you have perfect control over *everything* (at least I had and I worked quite a bit with this stuff, the major problem is figuring out the best estimate of the DPI reliably in the browser, but you already have that)

Comment: If I know the dpi and the screen resolution, how would that translate to number of pixels?

Comment: Width x Height = *always* the number of pixels if `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` as far as I know. DPI only describes the size *in real life*. So it describes how wide and heigh a pixel is.

Comment: That's true if the device-dpi is selected, but my question is more generic than that. Given the same screen size and different dpi, how to get the available pixels?

Comment: That's why I asked the question on Apr 24 at 20:55 ;-) . If you're not using it you can get the *real* width and height in java and send it to your app after which the same applies as above. And then if so you wish you can do some manual scaling based on the ratio between reported width/height and java width/height and the xdpi and ydpi.

Comment: Thing is that the reported width in Java !== usable pixels in HTML *unless* device-dpi is used; I'm currently using that because my app (luckily) only needs to run on one phone. It would be nice to have something generic though, but perhaps I'm just going at this the wrong way? Not sure, but it seems like a missing feature in JavaScript.

Comment: You might wanna read this article http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/more_about_devi.html I think I finally understood what you're looking for, my bad and in that case that article should help you out a bit understanding the rest. And for your **problem 1** you would have to add `width=device-width`

Comment: I've read that before, but I'll read it in more detail; mobile development ain't my forte and online material is quickly outdated :) in the meantime I'll award the bounty given the time you spent trying to help me.

Comment: Thx :) Honestly, serious cross browser mobile development is a crime. I tend to in general just 'by-pass' all the real problems by using a bit of an over jealous viewport definition... which is fine for true web applications I am building, but might and is not acceptable in a lot of other situations. And with over jealous I mean `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0" />`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use CSS media queries to target what you want to target?

If so, maybe you can solve your problem with [matchMedia.js](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) -- a cross-browser solution for testing media queries in JavaScript. Something to consider, right? Since you would have, in addition to size queries, `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio` at your disposal (mentioned in that guide you linked to)?